# insert xml node after last instance of same name

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba, msxml

I am using Microsoft Access and have the Microsoft XML, v6.0 library referenced in VBA. I can successfully load an external XML file to "xd" which is a MSXML2.DOMDocument60 object. I want to copy the contents of the LCR element and insert a new one after the last one in xd. I've tried various ways to use importnode and clonenode but don't know how to do it. I would prefer to used a method from this library to accomplish this and not an xsl transform. In the future, there could be other elements with other names besides LCR after the end of BAG.  please advise.

```
<TRANSMISSION>
<BAG>
<LCR id = "" and IsGood = "false"></LCR>
<LCR id = "abc" and IsGood = "false"></LCR>
<ICAT>
</ICAT>
</BAG>
</TRANSMISSION>
```

Expected Results:

```
<TRANSMISSION>
<BAG>
<LCR id = "" and IsGood = "false"></LCR>
<LCR id = "abc" and IsGood = "false"></LCR>
<LCR id = "" and IsGood = "false"></LCR>
<ICAT>
</ICAT>
</BAG>
</TRANSMISSION>
```

Comment: You need 2 documents, a source and a target.  To copy an element from source to the target document element like target.documentElement.appendChild( ndCopy ) where ndCopy is the element in your source.

Comment: When I use appendchild to my source, I am getting the element in the wrong place.  

    Set xOrig = xd.selectSingleNode        ("TRANSMISSION/BAG/LCR")
        '
         xd.documentElement.appendChild xOrig

I need to copy the LCR n times in the appropriate place, which is at the end within BAG not TRANSMISSION.

Comment: OK, hard to help without your code...  but, instead of appending to target.documentElement, append to the element you want to append to.  In your target document, select your target (ndTarget = target.selectSingleNode("//BAG"), then run ndTarget.appendChild(ndCopy).

Comment: This method works but the new children, i.e. instances of LCR beyond the first, are appearing after ICAT in my example. I need the LCR elements to appear together.

Comment: I'm not sure why the exact position is important, sounds cosmetic only.  But if you have to... make your target the ICAT element, and use insertBefore here's a link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754519(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Pls consider recognizing those that helped you on SO by accepting an answer to the other 10 questions you've posted, none of them have an accepted answer...